# How do I know the cyclic subgroups of G generated by a are equal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, divisibility, cyclic-groups

I had a question of understanding that I was hoping you guys could help me with. Suppose there exists a group in the integers. For the sake of my understanding, let's say the group is, G = $Z_{60}$. The cyclic subgroup of G generated by some a is (a) = {$n*a$ for $n$ in $ Z$}. So for example the cyclic subgroup <45> in G is {$0,15,30,45$}. By the same token, the cyclic subgroup <15> in  G is {$0,15,30,45$}.

I know there is some relation between gcd(a,|G|) (|G| being the cardinality or order of G), but I can't explain it. Returning to our example, the gcd(45,60) is 15 (which is the reason that they have the same cyclic subgroup in $Z_{60}$, but why is that so?

Would someone be able to give me a very simplified explanation into this? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I apologize ahead of time for any formatting issues - I'm not quite a master of the syntax yet!

Comment: Is your question for a general group $G$? In this case, your group $\mathbb Z_{60}$ is itself cyclic, which makes a difference

Comment: Would it be possible to address both? I'm not quite sure how the group being cyclic would impact it?

Comment: I don't think the question wouldn't make much sense for groups in general. All the notation you use is for cyclic groups $(\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$. Correct me and formulate the question for the general case if I'm wrong.